# Seeking resolution to a baffling Pattern oriented exception being thrown

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression that checks whether the Path entered by the end-user is accurate or not.
Here's my program:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Iterable<Path> dirs = FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories();
    StringBuilder dirNames = new StringBuilder("[");
    for(Path auxiliary : dirs)
    {
        dirNames.append("[").append(auxiliary).append("]");
    }
    dirNames.append("]");
    String separator = FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(dirNames + "[[[[\\w]&&[^_]]+?[separator]]{0,}?][[\\w&&
    [^_]]{1,}?]");

    Matcher m = p.matcher(br.readLine());
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

This is throwing an exception as follows:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 76
[[C:\][D:\][E:\][F:\][G:\]][[[[\w]&&[^_]]+[separator]]{0,}?][[\w&&[^_]]{1,}?]
                                                                            ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2548)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Pattern.java:2504)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2063)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at scanxan.ScanXan.main(ScanXan.java:24)
    Java Result: 1
```

Something's wrong with my regular expression. I'm perplexed and can't figure out what's wrong!

Comment: I inserted it at http://regex101.com/ and it showed no problem.

Comment: In Java the `&&` in the class is an intersection. I didn't get a parse  error, but your regex contains just two classes side by side `[[[[\w]&&[^_]]+?[separator]]{0,}?]` and `[[\w&&[^_]]{1,}?]` Can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: So, looks like your dirNames `[[C:\][D:\][E:\][F:\][G:\]]` contain a bunch of opening `[` without corresponding closeing `]`.

Comment: In the regular expression '[[[[\w]&&[^_]]+?[separator]]{0,}?]', [[\w]&&[^_]]+? is for matching a sequence of characters, followed by separator which constitutes the Path separator supported by the underlying OS, followed by [[\w&&[^_]]{1,}?], which is for matching one more sequence of characters that is not followed by the native Path separator.

Comment: I'm afraid you have enclosed everything in character classes.

Comment: I wish to check if the user has entered an accurate Path, for instance, something similar to this: D:\Movies\Imagine

Comment: Your pattern is completely wrong. It should look like this: `(?:C:\\|D:\\|E:\\)(?:\w+(?:separator)?)*`, where `separator` is the content of your "separator" variable.

Comment: You have to break things up. As it is now, you have enclosed everything into 2 classes. So it will only match 2 characters. If you trim off some of the class brackets you probably mean something like `[\w&&[^_]]+?[separator]{0,}[\w&&[^_]]{1,}`

Comment: So, given @Rawing is on the right track, you just have to construct a regex part out of `dirNames` the put it in front.

Comment: I tried this via NetBeans as follows:
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:C:\\|D:\\|E:\\)(?:\\w+(?:"+separator+")?)*");

and this resulted in an exception being thrown as listed below:

Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed group near index 29
(?:C:\|D:\|E:\)(?:\w+(?:\)?)*
                             ^
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.accept(Pattern.java:1813)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2908)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2051)

Comment: at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.group0(Pattern.java:2821)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2051)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
 at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
 at scanxan.ScanXan.main(ScanXan.java:30)
Java Result: 1

Comment: gee, I have no idea how to grey certain characters in your comments to make them stand out!